# How to access the path mentioned in gulp.src from the gulp.dest function?

Tags: regex, gulp

I use a regex based path in the gulp.src function i.e.,

```
gulp.task('gen-templateCache', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/client/pages/**/views/**/markup/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('new-templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            //Access the src path
            //Generate and Return the dest path based on the src path
        }));
});
```

As you can see I am using a regex `'app/client/pages/**/views/**/markup/*.html'` to generate the src path of this gulp task, because my source files are located in multiple folders.

My requirement is I need to also save my result in multiple folders relative to my src.

i.e., Let's say my gulp task resultant file is `'template.js'`. Now I want to save this result in `'app/client/pages/**/views/template.js'`

How can I do this?

Comment: Check [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename) plugin.

Comment: changing the filepath.dirname and filepath.basename was not doing the job for me for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not able to still find a generic solution to this problem but I was able to successfully find a solution that suited my particular gulp task :

Basically the task I was performing on the src file was 'gulp-angular-templatecache'(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache)

```
gulp.task('gen-templateCache', function() {
    var destination = '';
    return gulp.src('app/client/pages/**/views/**/markup/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('partials.js', {
            root: '',
            module: 'pageApp',
            transformUrl: function(url) {
                var ind = url.lastIndexOf('\\');
                var partialName = url.substring(ind+1);
                var viewsIndex = url.indexOf('\\views\\');
                var viewsPath = url.substring(0,viewsIndex+7);
                destination = "./app/client/pages/"+viewsPath;
                return partialName;
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function() {
            return destination;
        }));
});
```

This solution only works in the case of above task because the above task takes an option called transformUrl in the second parameter which inturn is a function with the file url as the parameter. But, I would still appreciate a generic solution.